# Email to BCC recepient is not sent

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email using

```
amazonSimpleEmailService.sendRawEmail
```

Sending an e-mail works only when the e-mail is sent to a person in the BCC header, and it does not work when someone is in the TO: or CC: section. does anyone know why? I couldn't find anything in the AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html

```
  public void send(Payload request) throws MessagingException, IOException {
      List<String> recipients = new LinkedList<>();

      String from = request.getFrom();
      String targetEmail = request.getRecipient();
      String ccEmail = request.getCc();
      String bccEmail = request.getBcc();

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

      message.setSubject(request.getSubject());
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
      if (targetEmail != null) {
          message.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(targetEmail));
          recipients.add(targetEmail);
      }
      if (ccEmail != null) {
          message.setRecipients(RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail));
          recipients.add(ccEmail);
      }
      if (bccEmail != null) {
          message.setRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(bccEmail));
          recipients.add(bccEmail);
      }
      MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      htmlPart.setContent(request.getBody(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8;");

      MimeMultipart bodyContainer = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
      bodyContainer.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

      MimeBodyPart htmlWrapper = new MimeBodyPart();
      htmlWrapper.setContent(bodyContainer);

      MimeMultipart messageContainer = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
      messageContainer.addBodyPart(htmlWrapper);

      Attachment attachment = request.getAttachment();
      if (Objects.nonNull(attachment)) {
          MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(attachment.getByteArrayDataSource());

          attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(dataHandler);
          attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(attachment.getFileName());

          messageContainer.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
      }

      message.setContent(messageContainer);

      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      message.writeTo(outputStream);

      RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));

      SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
      rawEmailRequest.withSource(from);
      rawEmailRequest.withDestinations(recipients);

      SendRawEmailResult sendRawEmailResult = amazonSimpleEmailService.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
      log.info("Email sent. MessageId: {}", targetEmail, ccEmail, bccEmail, sendRawEmailResult.getMessageId());
  }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that they are added BCC in the payload?

Comment: yes, it was provided @Ajris

Comment: I stated that it works when I have just a recipient in a BCC section. If I also put a recipient in a TO section, just that user gets an email

Comment: Please provide the whole raw Message and rawEmailRequest to analyze.

Comment: In case when I sent an email to a BCC recipient:
rawEmailRequest.destination contains that recipient, but  the BCC header is never set. Should i do it on some other way? I don't get it why message.setRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(bccEmail));
          don't work